# access: how to detect with VBA whether a query is opened?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

is it possible to detect whether there is an open query using VBA in access-2007?

i am opening a query like this:

```
    stDocName = "Meeting_Reasons_Frequency"
  DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName
```

is it possible to detect whether it is open?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
 If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, "QueryName") = acObjStateOpen Then
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa205281(office.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to queries, but I noticed that for forms, you should use `And` instead of `=`.

```
If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, "FormName") And acObjStateOpen Then
```

Apparently the form can have multiple "states" simultaneously. Using `And` picks out the one you want; it acts as a bitwise operator in this context.

Comment: The same `acSysCmdGetObjectState` issues apply to both queries and forms.  Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 1):

`SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, "QueryName")` returns zero if *QueryName* is closed or does not exist.

Otherwise it returns the sum of the constants for whichever of the following apply:

- `acObjStateOpen` (1) open in any state (new, dirty, etc.) or view (Design, Datasheet, etc.)
- `acObjStateDirty` (2) open but with unsaved design changes
- `acObjStateNew` (4) a new query which has not yet been saved to its parent collection (`QueryDefs`)

Perhaps most of the time checking whether the `SysCmd` expression `= acObjStateOpen` will be sufficient.  However if you want to avoid a surprise when the query is open with unsaved design changes you could `And acObjStateOpen` as [pianoJames suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488398/77335).

But if your intention is to do something when *QueryName* is open, you could simply check whether it is not closed (zero):

```vba
If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, "QueryName") <> 0 Then
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the end of this part `acObjStateOpen (1) open in any state (new, dirty, etc.)` because the other two constants represent dirty and new

Comment: If you open a saved query, its state will be just `acObjStateOpen` --- neither `acObjStateDirty` or `acObjStateNew` apply.